# Linked List Delete Node Function

Tags: java, linked-list

This code is supposed to delete every node from a linked list with a given value.

Are there any logical errors with this implementation? Did I do anything wrong or is there an area of this implementation that needs significant improvement. Any suggestions?

```
public boolean delete(int d) {
    Node tmpNode = head;
    Node prevNode = null;
    boolean deletedANode = false;

    if (head == null) {
        return deletedANode;
    }

    while (tmpNode != null) {
        if (tmpNode.data == d) {
            if (tmpNode == head) {
                head = head.next;
            }
            else {
                prevNode.next = tmpNode.next;
            }
         deletedANode = true;
         }

         prevNode = tmpNode;
         tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
    }

    return deletedANode;
}
```

Comment: You need to give some more detail on what the delete is supposed to do... like, at the moment it keeps searching even after it's deleted a node... is that intentional?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to delete every node with the value

Comment: I suggest renaming the method to `deleteAll(value)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is buggy, if you have two Nodes with the same value in succession it will corrupt the list....

`prevNode` will be set to the deleted node `tempNode`, and if the next value also matches the input value you will be working with the wrong node as `prevNode`.

Also, why is `d` a good name for the input search value?

To avoid future bugs it is convenient to mark constant input values as `final`. It also can potentially help with performance

You need to change some code:

```
// added final, change input to `searchValue`
public boolean delete(final int searchValue) {
    Node tmpNode = head;
    Node prevNode = null;
    boolean deletedANode = false;

    /*
    This code is redundant, the while-loop does the same effective thing.
    if (head == null) {
        return deletedANode;
    }
    */

    while (tmpNode != null) {
        if (tmpNode.data == searchValue) {
            if (tmpNode == head) {
                head = head.next;
            } else { // fixed indenting/newline
                prevNode.next = tmpNode.next;
            }
            // fixed indenting
            deletedANode = true;
         } else {
             // only advance the prevNode when there's no match.
             prevNode = tmpNode;
         }
         tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
    }

    return deletedANode;
}
```

Comment: Good catch with bug of wrongly advancing tmpNode. Thanks for the help.